# How can I remove "$MachineName" item from NotesAgent variable? Or how can I cast NotesAgent to NotesDocument so that I can remove this item?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have the following code:

```
Forall agent In db.agents
  'I need to remove "$MachineName" item from all agents
End Forall
```

How can I remove "$MachineName" item from NotesAgent? Or how can I cast NotesAgent to NotesDocument so that I can remove this item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to get the agents as design elements. This is possible with `NotesNoteCollection` class:

```vb
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim i As long
Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
Dim noteid As string

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
nc.SelectAgents = true
Call nc.BuildCollection
noteid = nc.Getfirstnoteid()
For i=1 To nc.Count
    Set doc = db.Getdocumentbyid(noteid)
    Call doc.Removeitem("$MachineName")
    Call doc.Save(true, true)
    noteid = nc.Getnextnoteid(noteid)
Next
```

Comment: This will invalidate the signature on the design element, however, so you must use the Sign method to sign the design note with an ID that the server recognizes as authorized, if you still want it to run.

Comment: @Andre thanks for your comment. We need an additional `Call doc.Sign()` before Save line to sign the agent with an authorized ID http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_SIGN_METHOD.html

Comment: I tried this to modify the server that a scheduled agent ran on, and I get these error messages on the console: 
"Agent Manager: Agent '<redacted>' has been corrupted.  Significant fields have been excluded from the signature." 
followed soon after by:
"AMgr: Error executing agent '<redacted>' in '<redacted servername>'. Agent signer '<redacted username (me)>': Unable to load agent; data is corrupt."
Any thoughts?

Comment: @Phil: open, change (e.g. add a space) and save the agent. This should set the missing internal fields. If it still doesn't work create a new question here on StackOverflow with more details.

Comment: Yes, that does work, but I have a LOT of agents where the server has been specified so I was hoping to do it in the backend.  Someone in their wisdom has decided to replace the server with a new one, and change its name :(
I might try DXL before opening a new question